# scale a [x,y,z] array with [x,y,1] shaped weights along z

Tags: numpy, product, multiplication, tensor, dot

TA.shape = (x,y,z)
TB.shape = (x,y,1)

func(TA,TB) : scale the TA's value with TB along z axis, returns (x,y,z) shaped array.

How to do this in numpy without duplicating TB's channel to (x,y,z)? Hopefully the question was clear~

Comment: Have you tried just `TA * TB`?  They should broadcast just fine if `TB.shape = (x, y, 1)`.

Comment: It works thought idk why...

Comment: Read up on [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)